# How to log backend request on Azure API Managment

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to record the timings for the backend web service being fronted by the API Management service.  We front a few 3rd party services so the only way we can get performance data is to log the backend request before and after.  My plan was to utilise the base policy (All APIs / All Operations) like this

```
<backend>
<!-- log start of request -->
<forward-request />
<!-- log end of request -->
</backend>
```

But trying this I get;

> Error in element 'backend' on line XX, column XX: backend section
>   allows only one policy to be specified

Can you have any policy expressions in the backend element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backend section is very limited in what policies are allowed there. Your best option would be to do your logging last thing in inbound and first thing in outbound. You can control what policy is executed first by moving "base" tag to a desired position, it effectively controls when (and if) upper level policies are executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Log to EventHub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn894085.aspx#log-to-eventhub) in this case to log whatever you want for a given request (which has Id you can use as correlation id).

Comment: My plan was to utilise the base policy (All APIs / All Operations), it appears that you cannot have any policy expressions in that policy level. I could do it at the operation level but that does not allow me to perform an expression before and after the backend forwards the request based on my testing.