# Azure API Management Log Backend Request to App Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Within the  area of the APIM Policy, using emit-metric to send the original call and client IP address to App Insights. I cannot find how to send the URI that is sent to the backend, which will not be the same as the original URI call due to transformations in the Policy.

Should the logging go into the  section?

Cannot seem to find the spot in the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log backend request on Azure API Managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467986/how-to-log-backend-request-on-azure-api-managment) and [How can I log to App Insights from Azure API Management 'send-request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170849/how-can-i-log-to-app-insights-from-azure-api-management-send-request)

Comment: You can refer to [How to integrate Azure API Management with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights) and [How to log request/response payload in Application Insights for APIs frontend by API Management](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip301.html)